# What is the difference between ServerName and ServerAlias in apache2 configuration?

Tags: configuration, apache2, webserver, ubuntu-12.04

I am configurating my apache2 server and I wonder whats the difference between ServerName and ServerAlias.

Is the ServerName always a name without www    as like google.de
and the ServerAlias is www.google.de

Even if it's like this, I don't get it :) sorry.

I am not a professional (now) so thank you for your help! Every help will upvoted immediately.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the [Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias):

> **`ServerName`:**
> Hostname and port that the server uses to identify itself
>
> **`ServerAlias`:**
> Alternate names for a host used when matching requests to name-virtual hosts

Most people simply use `ServerName` to set the 'main' address of the website (eg. 'mywebsite.com') and `ServerAlias` to add additional addresses the website will be bound to (eg. 'www.mywebsite.com').

Yet, there are subtle differences between the two:

- `ServerName` can accept port numbers as well, while `ServerAlias` cannot.
- `ServerAlias` can accept wildcards (eg. *.mywebsite.com), while `ServerName` cannot.

Read the documentation to understand why.